# Should I be using a different strategy than "SetEnv" for setting apache environment vars on 18.04?

Tags: apache2, python3, environment-variables

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, apache 2 and Python 3.6.  In my Python project settings file, I have

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASS'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DB_SERVICE'],
        'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT']
    }
}
```

In my Apache configuration file, /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf, I set up the envionrment variables like so

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName lab.chicommons.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web

    SetEnv DB_NAME maps_data
    SetEnv DB_USER chicommons
    SetEnv DB_PASS ChiCommons1$
    SetEnv DB_SERVICE localhost
    SetEnv DB_PORT 3306

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #Alias /static /srv/rdmo/rdmo-app/static_root/
        #<Directory /srv/rdmo/rdmo-app/static_root/>
        #    Require all granted
        #</Directory>
    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        WSGIDaemonProcess maps \
            home=/var/www/html/web python-home=/var/www/html/web/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup maps 
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/web/maps/wsgi.py process-group=maps
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        <Directory /var/www/html/web/maps>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Sadly my application is not finding the environment vars, giving the error

```
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.826760 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.826815 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.826887 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.826983 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.827042 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]   File "/var/www/html/web/maps/settings.py", line 84, in <module>
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.827091 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]     'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.827153 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.827221 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544]     raise KeyError(key) from None
[Mon Apr 20 17:23:12.827285 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3706:tid 140680830412544] KeyError: 'DB_NAME'
```

I'm starting and stopping Apache using

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you run your Python app

Comment: My bad, I included the complete virtual host configuration with the WSGI config.  Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Hello, can you show how you defined the application object ? It should have an "environ" parameter that allows you to access the variables defined in 000-default.conf.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean -- in what kind of file would I typically find an "environ" object?  Are you talking about the wsgi.py file?

Comment: If think you can use the thread on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016504/apache-setenv-not-working-as-expected-with-mod-wsgi

Comment: @MostafaNajafiyazdi, the link you posted has an answer that talks about Flask, but I'm not using Flask.  Is that the link you meant to post?

Comment: @Dave I did meant that link. It is talkig about the Flask, but the issue is the same WGSI environment, read the answer that was approved. It might give you a hint. I think your issue and the one explained there originate from the same palce.

Answer (score 0):

Hi no sure that do the trick but you can add some alias inside your profile or bashrc.

for exemple :

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Create your alias : at the end of the file

```
# MYSQL SITE X
alias DB_NAME='maps_data'
alias DB_USER='chicommons'
alias DB_PASS='ChiCommons1$'
alias DB_SERVICE='localhost'
alias DB_PORT='3306'
```

Apply this new bashrc directives.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

best regards

Comment: Unfortunately, the user under which Apache runs, www-data in my case, has no home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your application, you are calling os.environ['DB_NAME'], but that mapping object contains values coming from the shell environment from which your process exists.

But when you are using the directive WSGIDaemonProcess, you are launching another daemon process and this one doesn't heritate the environment variables defined by SetEnv.

When using SetEnv at expecting things to appears in os.environ, there are three important caveats to be aware of:

1. os.environ should not be confused with the WSGI environment object,
   which is often called env. The WSGI environment object is something
   totally different, and is for accessing per-request information.
   os.environ is for accessing OS-level environment variables.
2. os.environ does not change, so it must not be used for accessing per-request 
   environment variables whose values may change on a per-request basis. For 
   example, do not call os.environ['SSL_SESSION_ID'] because SSL_SESSION_ID 
   changes on a per-client basis.
3. If you spawn an application process, but not as part of handling a request, 
   then that application process will not have per-request environment variables 
   stored inside OS-level environment variables.

Therefore, you'd better define your values directly in your project setting file.
You can then use options of the WSGIDaemonProcess directive to eventually use different setting files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I'm clear, you recommend hard-coding the values in my ./apps/settings.py file?  If so, I feel taht's less than ideal because then the passwords get checked in to version control.